# Add key to set of objects within array's set given match condition of object's key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this problem which I have tried to solve to no avail.

In this array of arrays, when two or more color keys in the objects match with any other set of array's objects color keys, I would like to add a  boolean key called `match` to each of those array's objects, regardless of whether every key matches.

For example, two objects in the `data[0][0]` and `data[0][1]` arrays share the key `color` `white` and `black`, so that is a `match: true` for all objects in `data[0][0]` and `data[0][1]` but not `data[0][2]` as this only has one, therefore it will be `match: false`.

The result would look like this:

```
data = [
  [{
    name: 'car',
    color: 'black',
    group: 0,
    match: true
  },{
    name: 'car',
    color: 'white',
    group: 0,
    match: true
  },{
    name: 'car',
    color: 'blue',
    group: 0,
    match: true
  }],
  [{
    name: 'truck',
    color: 'black'
    group: 1,
    match: true
  },{
    name: 'truck',
    color: 'white',
    group: 1,
    match: true
  },{
    name: 'truck',
    color: 'yellow',
    group: 1,
    match: true
  }],
  [{
    name: 'moto',
    color: 'black',
    group: 2,
    match: false
  },{
    name: 'moto',
    color: 'pink',
    group: 2,
    match: false
  },{
    name: 'moto',
    color: 'orange',
    group: 2,
    match: false
  }]
]
```

*This is a small sample. The actual data has hundreds of arrays and the match should be a minimum of 7*

Comment: please add the original data and what you have tried.

Comment: Original data is the code above without the `match` key, I have tried numerous things including reduce and the like but nothing works, I did not want to pollute the question

Comment: please add what you have tried. above is only one data set. please add the missing one as well.

Comment: I see what you mean I made a mistake defining the data arrays, I am fixing it

Comment: What is the given data above. Input or expected output. Add the missing one

Comment: Expected output, input is the same data without the `match` keys

Comment: what happens if you have two white and one black?

Comment: There will be no duplicates within an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate an intersection of `colors` as an array and compare the `length` to your expected threshold to determine the value of `match` in your results.

```js
function match (data, key, filter, transform) {
  const arrays = data.map(
    array => array.map(key)
  );
  const groups = arrays.map(
    array => ({ array, set: new Set(array) })
  );
  const matches = groups.map(
    outer => groups.some(
      inner => (
        outer !== inner &&
        filter(outer.array.filter(inner.set.has, inner.set))
      )
    )
  );

  return data.map(
    (array, index) => transform(array, matches[index])
  );
}

const data = [[{name:'car',color:'black',group:0},{name:'car',color:'white',group:0},{name:'car',color:'blue',group:0}],[{name:'truck',color:'black',group:1},{name:'truck',color:'white',group:1},{name:'truck',color:'yellow',group:1}],[{name:'moto',color:'black',group:2},{name:'moto',color:'pink',group:2},{name:'moto',color:'orange',group:2}]];

const result = match(
  data,
  value => value.color,
  keys => keys.length >= 2,
  (array, match) => array.map(
    value => Object.assign(value, { match })
  )
);

console.log(result);
```

This creates a [`Set()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for each array of `colors` to more efficiently calculate the intersection at each pass without skipping duplicates, if there are any.

For your actual data, you can change the `filter` parameter to

```
colors => colors.length >= 7
```

Comment: Amazing many thanks, works with the sample, I am running the full sample and converting to csv, and double check but the logic is impressive,

Comment: @Álvaro By the way, if you don't want to mutate the original data, you can change the `Object.assign(v, { match })` to `({ ...v, match })`.

Comment: Thanks, mutating the data is not a problem cause it actually comes from a csv that I converted earlier

Comment: Could  the match function be modify if I wanted to add a key with the group it matches with, and adding extra keys if more than one group matches?

Comment: @Álvaro I think that would warrant a new question, but the second part could be done with multiple calls to the function, yes?

Answer (score 0):

You could count black and white and get new objects with `match`.

```js
var data = [[{ name: 'car', color: 'black', group: 0 }, { name: 'car', color: 'white', group: 0 }, { name: 'car', color: 'blue', group: 0 }], [{ name: 'truck', color: 'black', group: 1 }, { name: 'truck', color: 'white', group: 1 }, { name: 'truck', color: 'yellow', group: 1 }], [{ name: 'moto', color: 'black', group: 2 }, { name: 'moto', color: 'pink', group: 2 }, { name: 'moto', color: 'orange', group: 2 }]],
    result = data.map(a => {
        var count = {},
            match = a.some(({ color }) => {
                count[color] = (count[color] || 0) + 1;
                return count.black === 1 && count.white === 1;
            });
        return a.map(o => Object.assign({}, o, { match }));
    });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I don't think the specific colors black and white had anything to do with the algorithm...